# Почему не корректный вывод key, lambda?

Tags: python

Почему выводится максимальное число, кратное двум - 14?
Ведь должен вывести 100:

```
lst = [77, 14, 5, 9, 277, 100]
print(max(lst, key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
```

А если вместо max написать min, то вообще выведет число не кратное двум? Какая тут связь?

Comment: Потому что сравнение выполняется по прописанному вами key, а ваш key возвращает только два возможных значения — True и False. Разумеется, эти два значения никогда не дадут адекватный результат

Comment: Вероятно, вы хотели написать что-то вроде `max(x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @andreymal в числе 14 он получил True, но это же возможно еще не максимум. Почему он дальше не продолжает искать элемент? Там же стоит max, а это возможно и не максимум

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296814/4928642

Comment: @Дима для числа 14 он получил True, для числа 100 он тоже получил True. Что по-вашему больше — True или True?

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: C min аналогично, только наоборот, для нечётных чисел получается False, а False всегда меньше чем True, поэтому минимальным будет считаться какое-нибудь из нечётных чисел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргумент key в max отвечает за способ выбора наибольшего, а не за фильтрацию.
Код должен выглядеть так

```
lst = [77, 14, 5, 9, 277, 100]
print(max(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst)))
```

Твой же код находил первое чётное число. Когда ты задал аргумент key таким образом, список превратился в [False, True, False, False, False, True], и вполне логично, что первый максимум тут второй элемент, который в изначальном списке имеет значение 14.